# Should we explicitly declare the type of a variable in typescript?

Tags: typescript

These 2 code snippets have the same result (both throw an error):

```
let a = 'a'
a = 123
```

And

```
let a: string = 'a'
a = 123
```

It seems even when we don't explicitly declare that `a` is a string, typescript still make its type a string. In this case, is it necessary to explicitly declare the type of a variable?

Comment: If it helps you as a programmer, you are free to manually annotate all of your types. If you don't annotate a type, and TypeScript can't figure it out or infers the wrong type (or you make an error, etc.), you'll get a compiler diagnostic. That being said, Stack Overflow is not really the right place to ask for "best practice" kinds of questions. Check out some TypeScript in large, active codebases in GitHub to see what other people are doing.

Comment: @jsejcksn I didn't realize that this is a question about best practice at first.

Comment: No worries, and good luck with your TypeScript programming!

Comment: @jsejcksn Thanks. I should read the ts doc carefully. Just found it mentioned about type inferrence and type annotation.